# Python code for Fibonacci

Tags: loops, python-3.x, fibonacci

The below code works fine but can some one explain me whats happening after the sentence
`for i in range(n)`
how does the value change or how is it getting added when i enter different value for `n`.

the code is a s follows:-

```
def fib():

    old = 0
    new = 1
    new_num = 1 #fibonacci number which will change
                #depending on the value of n.

    n = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    for i in range(n):
        new_num = old + new
        new = old
        old = new_num
        new_num = new_num

    if n <= 0:
            print ("Please enter a number greater than 0.")
    elif n == 1:
            print ("The value is 1.")
    else:
            print ("The value is %s." % (new_num))

fib()
```

Like I mentioned, i get the correct answer, but I cant fully understand how the code is working and changing the value **SINCE "N" IS NOT LINKED TO ANYTHING.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run through the loop you are replacing the older numbers with the ones you just created. `n` is equal to whatever you typed in. Let's say you typed in a `4`. The for loop will run from 0 to 3 ( 4 times). First it is adding the values of `old` and `new` to create `new_num` now that you have the next number in the series, it is then overwriting the old values of `old` and `new` to the last two values in the series. It keeps doing this until the loop ends.

> when i = 0; old = 0; new = 1; new_num = 1
>
> when i = 1; old = 1; new = 1; new_num = 2
>
> when i = 2; old = 2; new = 1; new_num = 3
>
> when i = 3; old = 3; new = 2; new_num = 5

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be used to for loops from C or another language with similar constructs.  In Python, `for i in range(n):` means "run the code inside this block once for each value in the list of numbers between `0` and `n-1`, setting `i` to each number in turn".  (Technically in Python 3 it's not a list but an iterator that generates the numbers sequentially without storing them in a list, but the difference is academic in this case.)

So:

1. `n` is set from user input by the `input()` function.
2. `n` is used as an argument for the `range()` function, which of course does not change the value of `n` (it just creates a list of `n` numbers).  The `for` loop then executes once for each number in the list.
3. `n` is used to determine the output in the `if`/`elif`/`else` statement, again without changing the value of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop executes n times.  Each time the loop executes, it calculates the i-th value based on the previous calculated values.  It doesn't change n, just uses n as an indication of how many times it has to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

I commented your code for you. What you should know 100% before trying to understand your code is that a Fibonacci number is the sum of the two numbers, in the sequence, before it.

This is important to know, as the "new" and "old" are place holders.

**Also Note: ** N is linked to something, the range. N decides what index in the Fibonacci range you'd like to determine.

```
def fib():

new = 1
old = 0
new_num = 1 #fibonacci number which will change
            #depending on the value of n.

n = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

for i in range(n):  # This is where the value of N is used 
    new_num = new + old  # new_num is the fibonacchi number at index "i", so to get it add the two before us
    old = new  # Update the old place holder (which is what new was, as we're updating new next)
    new = new_num  # Update new to be what we just calculating, so we can use it on the next iteration
    new_num = new_num  # Does nothing. Remove this line

if n <= 0:
        print ("Please enter a number greater than 0.")
elif n == 1:
        print ("The value is 1.")
else:
        print ("The value is %s." % (new_num))

fib()
```

As always, any questions, just add a comment below!